# C++ calls Java-NoClassDefFoundError

Tags: java, c++

I can debug my java application on eclipse,everything seems OK.But when I used C++ to call the class and catch the exception,I got the error:

```
 Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: ParserDemo/ParserNP 
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: ParserDemo.ParserNP
  at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:331)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
```

OS:Windows

java version 1.8

How can I fix it?
Thanks :)

edit:
My c++ code:

```
    int res;                     
JavaVMInitArgs vm_args;       
JavaVMOption options[3];     
JavaVM *jvm;           
JNIEnv *env;                            

options[0].optionString = "-Djava.compiler=NONE";  
options[1].optionString ="-Djava.class.path=.";
options[2].optionString = "-verbose:NONE"; 

vm_args.version = JNI_VERSION_1_8;  
vm_args.nOptions = 3;   
vm_args.options = options;   
vm_args.ignoreUnrecognized = JNI_TRUE;  

typedef jint (WINAPI *PFunCreateJavaVM)(JavaVM **, void **, void *);  
const wchar_t szJvmPath[]=L"C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Java\\jdk1.8.0_112\\jre\\bin\\client\\jvm.dll";

HINSTANCE hInstance = ::LoadLibrary(szJvmPath);  

if (hInstance == NULL)     
{     
    cout<< "LoadLibrary False"<<endl;  
    cout<<::GetLastError()<<endl;  
    return -2;     
}  
PFunCreateJavaVM funCreateJavaVM = (PFunCreateJavaVM)::GetProcAddress(hInstance, "JNI_CreateJavaVM");  
res = (*funCreateJavaVM)(&jvm, (void**)&env, &vm_args); 
if (res < 0)  
{  
    return -1; 
}      jclass cls = env->FindClass("ParserDemo/ParserNP");
   jthrowable exc;
   exc=env->ExceptionOccurred();


if(exc){
    jclass newExcCls;
    env->ExceptionDescribe();
    env->ExceptionClear();}
```

Comment: Its impossible to tell you how to fix this if you dont show us how you are calling the java code from C++.

Comment: The problem is seems to be a wrong classpath for java, but yes, show how are you calling it from C++

Comment: Now you can see my code.And I put all the jar files and the c++ project(.vcxproj) under the same directory.Is that right?

Comment: Is it `package ParserDemo; ... public class ParserNP {`? (Unusual to use capitals in package names.)

Comment: Yes,but I changed package name to parserdemo,still got that error.